# How to finish entering keyboard shortcut dialog in keyboard app? Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I want to add shortcut for `gnome-screenshot -ac` with using shift and printscreen button. 
But I can't figure out how to finish the enter shortcut dialog?

Already pressed shift + printscreen, tried other key too. it just won't dissappear and save the key shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Unity or Gnome by default?

Comment: I believe I'm using Gnome, just installed Ubuntu and just choose the default option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have printscreen bound to something already?

You may have to unbind printscreen first as it's interrupting the binding of shift+printscreen, then bind shift+printscreen and finally, rebind printscreen.

You don't have to press Enter after creating a keybind, it will automatically disappear and show you the bound keys once all keys are not pressed anymore. This is why I think printscreen is bound to something and interrupting the new keybind.

Comment: it's bind to screenshot feature but its not copying to clipboard. and it doesn't show on the keyboard shortcut list so I can't unbind the key

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.04, Shift+Print appears under the "Screenshots" list of keys. In addition, when I try to set the hotkey, I get a warning the key is already assigned. So Gnome may have been improving on this point.

Comment: @vanadium ok, so I found the original shortcut, rebind to something else and I can use shift + print key combination

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable the Shift+PrintSc Shortcut

[image]

[image]

2. Add Custom Shortcut with Shift+Printsc

[image]